# Play multiple videos at the same time ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I want to play a list of videos at the same time(one after other, just like 1 video)

I’m now using ExoPlayer to play those videos, but I cannot buffer next video when the current video is playing. So it can’t look like one video, there is delay when switch between two videos.

Any one has solution for this, please?

Comment: I'm confused. You want to play several videos at the same time in one view, like 4 videos in a grid, combining all their audio into one stream? Or you want to play one video, but start buffering a follow up video before the current one ends so the second can start immediately after the first finishes?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What I want is the second one. Play one video and start buffer a follow up video. Could you help me please!

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem,

change line 360 :codec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(codecName) to codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mimeType) in MediaCodecTrackRenderer class.

looks like exoplayer try to use more than one hardware decoder but some devices does not allow more than one hardware decoders.

the changes will let exoplayer to pick software decoder if hardware decoders are allocated.